# DBContext custom validations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, dbcontext

Relatively new to DBContext and trying to write custom validations in DBContext **without** implementing the **IValidatableObject** interface or **ValidateEntity** override.

e.g.
For a Department entity that has:
Name
Trasit#
BLID

Here is a snippet of the save logic:

```
public static Boolean saveDepartmentDetails(Department dept, out string errorMessage)
{
Boolean isSuccessful = false;
Int32 iRetVal = 0;
errorMessage = string.Empty;

using (OnlineFormsEntities context = new OnlineFormsEntities())
{
    if (dept != null)
    {
        if (dept.DepartmentID > 0)
        {
            //Todo: I know this is wrong.
            if (context.Departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentName.ToLower() == dept.DepartmentName.ToLower() && d.DepartmentID != dept.DepartmentID).Count() > 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "A Department with the given name already exists.";
                return false;
            }
            if (context.Departments.Where(d => d.Transit.ToLower() == dept.Transit.ToLower() && d.DepartmentID != dept.DepartmentID).Count() > 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "A Department with the given Transit # already exists.";
                return false;
            }

            context.Departments.Attach(dept);
            context.Entry(dept).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            if (context.Departments.Where(d => d.DepartmentName.ToLower() == dept.DepartmentName.ToLower()).Count() > 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "A Department with the given name already exists.";
                return false;
            }
            if (context.Departments.Where(d => d.Transit.ToLower() == dept.Transit.ToLower()).Count() > 0)
            {
                errorMessage = "A Department with the given Transit # already exists.";
                return false;
            }

            context.Departments.Add(dept);
        }

        try
        {
            iRetVal = context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException opEx)
        {
            errorMessage = opEx.Message;
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, dept);
            iRetVal = context.SaveChanges();
        }
        isSuccessful = (iRetVal > 0) ? true : false;
    }
}
return isSuccessful;
}
```

I need help with the update logic. Or a better way of coding this SaveDepartmentDetails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend pulling out all of the common logic into a Validation method in that same class that you're saving in (i.e. a method that returns a `bool` value: True if it passes, False if it doesn't. You can have error message being used as an `out` parameter as well):

```
private bool ValidateDept(OnlineFormsEntities context, Department dept, out string errorMessage)
{
  errorMessage = string.empty;

  if (context.Departments.Any(d => d.DepartmentName.ToLower() == dept.DepartmentName.ToLower() && d.ID != dept.ID))
   {
     errorMessage = "A Department with the given name already exists.";
     return false;
   }
 if (context.Departments.Any(d => d.Transit.ToLower() == dept.Transit.ToLower() && d.ID != dept.ID))
   {
     errorMessage = "A Department with the given Transit # already exists.";
     return false;
  }
 return true;
}
```

Doing this, then, will allow you to do call this validation method at the beginning of your save method and then only doing the add/attach after it passes.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with your logic. Is there a better way to do validations though? As I'm assuming that the checks my code are doing a database call both times. Right? Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't think of one. You want to validate to make sure that those values are not already present in the database. To do so you'd either have to actually go to the database and ask, or (worse) cache all of the database values at the beginning of your program and then just go to that later (horrible memory usage). You're best bet is to just put the validation like this.

Comment: The .Any(), will it work on updating as well? I'd assume the if condition will always evaluate to true in the case of update as there would always be a department with the given name or transit.